# Simple obj preview with ARCore

Tags: android, 3d-model, arcore

is there any way to show obj on glsurfaceview with ARCore but without camera and without implementing whole logic of renderer, I mean only preview of model, and for example after click, show model on camera. For example library that load preview of model and model in AR. 
I know that I can use some library for load model to glsurfaceview and ARCore to load model to AR, but I ask if is some library that do all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare two activities. In first one you can make list of models for preview, after taping on the model you can pass some identifier of it to the second activity that will enable the camera and show it in front of the user.

Remember that the fact you`re using ARCore is not forcing you to do it in every single place and activity

I hope this what you had in mind

Comment: This is not what I mean. I mean that in preview I show 3d model in glsurfaceview. And I can use one library for all. And no one library for preview and one for AR.

Comment: you need glsurface to display 3D objects generated by OpenGL, you also need glsurface to display effects of ARCore. Maybe I'm missing something so try to rephrase your question

Comment: @MichaelDrdlíček: I am also searching the same thing. I found to render 3D object (jpct-ae), but I am not able to get how to attach it to ARCore.